# Android - Room autoGenerate not found

Tags: android, primary-key, auto-generate, android-room

I am trying to make an id as primary key and set it to autoGenerate. Somehow, when I compile my code I get this error:

> "autoGenerate not found"

Here is my code:

```
@Entity
public class Preference {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    public void setId(int id) {

    this.id = id;

}
```

---

Comment: Did you work this out? What package is your `@PrimaryKey` annotation from?  If it isn't `android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey` then you've pulled in the annotation from some other library and that probably doesn't have the autoGenerate value property.